# ES6 import: how to define evaluating order (problem with `new Date()`)?

Tags: date, import, zod

Considering this `user` schema (not `zod`-related):

```
// user.ts

import { z } from 'zod'
    
export const User = z.object({
  created_at: z.string().default(new Date()), // Note the new Date() here
  email: z.string().email(),
})

export type User = z.infer<typeof User>
```

...and considering I wrote somewhere else a test to make sure my `user` object is good:

```
// user.test.ts

import { User } from 'user.ts'

it('should return a good user', () => {

   // 1. I mock the date
   setSystemTime(new Date('2100-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'))
   console.log('The Proof: ', new Date()) // It works: returns 2100-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

  // Zod.parse my user
  const input = User.parse({ email: 'test@example.org })

  // ... and see that the mocked date isn't used
  console.log('The Zod-parsed input: ', input)
  // { created_at: "2023-07-05T12:32:38", email: "test@example.org" }

  // Thus a failing test
  expect(input.created_at).toBe('2100-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')
})
```

I've very recently understood that it's because, in `test.ts`, `import { User } from 'user.ts'` is evaluated BEFORE I set my mocked date. Thus the error.

However I don't now/understand how to fix this...
Any clue? Thanks.